# Auto Signout timer in app?

Tags: ios, nstimer, touchesbegan, touches

What I need to do is this; I will have a timer that will tick away and when 30 minutes is up I'll auto signout the user. But if there's any interaction with the application I will reset the timer to 30 min. I have an idea on what to do but I'm sure there's a better way to accomplish this.

What I'll do is make a singleton class that holds a timer and posts a notification when the timer is up. So what I'm thinking is I'll have to reset the timer when ever the user presses a button, goes to the next screen etc.

My quesiton though is is it possible to respond to any touches in the app in one piece of code? Like somehow there's a superclass I can add this to and it will always reset the timer no matter what kind of interaction has happened? Or do I need to add the code to all the places where the user will interact with the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, subclass `UIApplication` and add following code in implementation

```
@implementation MyApplication

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self reset];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)reset {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(logout) object:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(logout) withObject:nil afterDelay:30*60];
}

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];

    [self reset];
    NSLog(@"event detected");
}

- (void)logout {
    NSLog(@"logout now");
}
@end
```

Then in `main.m` change the implementation like this

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([MyApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Here what is happening is, `- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method will get called after each user activity, Then we are registering a perform selector request after 30 mins. Once user touches the screen within 30 mins cancel previous request and register new one.

Comment: Thanks ill try this out when i have time. Still working on something else. It looks like exactly what i need. So if i look in the ```UIApplication``` class I should see a method called ```-(void)senEvent)``` Which is called everytime an event occurs in the application. Im wondering whats the scope of the events the method will be called upon and well how this method interacts with the system

Comment: interaction of this event and rest of application is handled in ui application class. thats why we calling super method. if u comment super call nothing will happen I guess(not checked that case)